# changing select option dropdownlist with onclick function button

Tags: javascript, html

i want to change dropdown lists with some buttons,
i tried this below codes but it doesnt act like what i want,

if i click the buttons, it creates an extra option, this is ok, no problem, 
(actually i want change between three existing option, not new one)

normally if i click directly to the existing "option 2", another div element shows text2 with ajax,
but if i create a selected "option 2", the div element doesnt refresh, after i click to refresh, div element shown correctly

```
<select id="id1">
 <option value="1">existingshow1</option>
 <option value="2">existingshow2</option>
 <option value="3">existingshow3</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction1()">111</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">222</button>
<button onclick="myFunction3()">333</button>

<script>
function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.createElement("OPTION");
    x.setAttribute("value", "1");
    var t = document.createTextNode("show1");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(x).selected = "true";
}

function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.createElement("OPTION");
    x.setAttribute("value", "2");
    var t = document.createTextNode("show2");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(x).selected = "true";
}

function myFunction3() {
    var x = document.createElement("OPTION");
    x.setAttribute("value", "3");
    var t = document.createTextNode("show3");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(x).selected = "true";
}
</script>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Where is the div and how you added eventlistener?

Comment: after the selects comes div, but div element created with buddypress activity.
actually i hate dropdown list, i want buttons, and i dont know how i change,
here is an example, but i delete it soon; http://benceboyle.net/

Answer (score 2):

We have an html:

```
<select id="id1" onChange="onChange(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<button onclick="addOption();">Add option</button>
```

Onchange - event, called when select changed

Javascript:

```
window.addOption = function (){
  var x = document.createElement('option');
  x.setAttribute("value", "new value");
  var t = document.createTextNode("show1");
  x.appendChild(t);

  var select = document.getElementById("id1");
  select.appendChild(x).selected = "true";

  // Trigger select change
  select.onchange();
}
```

Onchange callback for select

```
window.onChange = function(select){
  console.log('Select value is: ', select.value);
}
```

Try: https://jsfiddle.net/otLmwv20/

Comment: sorry it works in jsfiddle, i see but it doenst work for me.
it doesnt refresh also

Comment: http://benceboyle.net/ 
it is an other language but you can see a link named (yenile)
in the middle of the content, near the rss button, everything is there

Answer (score 1):

Hi if i understand correctly here is an example of what you could do also:

In your html code I use classes to dont declare functions by each element, and the data attributes to associate for each button different actions.

```
<select id="id1">
 <option value="1">existingshow1</option>
 <option value="2">existingshow2</option>
 <option value="3">existingshow3</option>
</select>

<button class="buttonAction" data-option="1">111</button>
<button class="buttonAction" data-option="2">222</button>
<button class="buttonAction" data-option="3">333</button>

<div id="idLoadAjax">
</div>
```

In the JS code is quite simple

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id1').change(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
        loadAjaxContent($(this).val());

    });

    $('.buttonAction').click(function(){
        $('#id1').val($(this).data('option'));
        console.log($(this).data('option'));    
        loadAjaxContent($(this).data('option'));
    });
});

function loadAjaxContent(optionId) {
    $('#idLoadAjax').text("Hey there: " + optionId);
    //$('#idLoadAjax').load(URL);
}
```

This code should refresh your div content for each time you change your select option or click one of the buttons, I also understand you dont need create new options when the user click on the buttons then i didnt add that logic, tell me if i understand it correctly.

Thanks

Comment: yes u understand it correctly, and works fine also... thak you so much

Answer (score 0):

i got an other idea:

there is a refresh link

```
<a href="/refresh-div">refresh it</a>
```

it refreshs the expected div, it works fine,

when i click the button 1, it clicks also to the refresh link, 
is it possible?

Comment: you may programmatically click this button, you need get element and then use element.click() For example: `var a = document.getElementById('button_id'); a.click();`

Comment: okey it works now superbly, thanks a lot, i need to learn javascript as soon as possible